# Usage of だけにしか in XとYだけにしか見えない

Tags: grammar, particle-に, particle-だけ, particle-しか

> ハグリッドと自分**だけにしか**見えないんじゃないか、とハリーは思ったが、...
> Harry wondered if it wasn't visible to any one except him and Hagrid, ...

It seems that I could remove だけに from this sentence and preserve the meaning.
I assumed that Xしか or XとYしか where exhaustive in the sense that XとYしか見えない means that it is invisible to every single person except X and Y. Is this true? If so, then adding だけに seems like a tautology.

Am I missing something? Is だけに redundant? Is it just adding emphasis? What's going on here?

I also wonder how this works grammatically. What purpose is に serving?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

だけ is redundant and can be removed, but I would leave に.

> ハグリッドと自分**にしか**見えないんじゃないか
> It may be visible only to Hagrid and me

This に plays a similar function to the “to” in “it wasn’t visible to…” Without it, the sentence could be ambiguous because ハグリッドと自分 could be understood as the only ones someone can see.

> ハグリッドと自分**しか**見えないんじゃないか
> They may be able to see only Hagrid and me
> (Only Hagrid and I may be visible)